# Decode Java Char / String

Tags: java, utf-8

I've a form with Primefaces. The header of the xml file looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```

When I send the form, I take the values with `HttpServletRequest`:

```
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {    
   String shortname = request.getParameter("shortname");
   (...)
```

Now when `shortname` contains a umlaute, for example an **ü**, the umlaute will be saved as UTF-8 encoded. So my **ü** get saved as **Ã¼**.

How can I decode it again? All the tutorials use a byte-array, but I haven't one.

I need this variable in a EMail, and it doesn't look really good with some hieroglyphics.

Comment: What happens if you override the request's encoding before calling getParameter?  e.g. call `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`?

Comment: Haha what. How simple is that?! Perfect! You can it post a a answer and i'll accept it.

Comment: Re-posted as an answer.  Glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell the `HttpServletRequest` instance that it's in UTF-8:

```
public String handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {    
   try {
       request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
       String shortname = request.getParameter("shortname");

       (...)
   }
   catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again! BTW, `setCharacterEncoding` should be surrounded by try/catch :)

Comment: Yeah you're right.  Serves me right for not actually compiling first :)